# SQLAlchemy / Python - SSL errors: "decryption failed or bad record mac" | "EOF detected"

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, python-multiprocessing, psycopg2

I have a Flask Python application where I'm using the multiprocessing library to execute a function in parallel with the main thread. The purpose of the function is to upload files to OneDrive. The function also needs to read and write from my DB.

My app uses a PostgreSQL database and SQLAlchemy. In order to access the DB from the temp threads, I'm creating a new SQLALchemy engine every time the function is executed. I'm getting a couple different errors when these temp threads are executing their function. The errors are very intermittent.

###### This error occurs most often (full stack trace further down), and doesn't actually seem to cause any side effects in my app. Code continues executing:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL error: decryption failed or bad record mac
```

###### This error occurs less often, but it causes a screen crash and prevents some of the function execution:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

I've tried to research these errors, but many of the posts I've found have different enough setups that I'm not sure if they apply in my case. I've tried some of the solutions suggested in those posts but they are not preventing the errors. I'm not very experienced with SQLAlchemy so I'm flying blind here.

###### Here is my code that spawns the temp threads:

```py
    # Initialize the class that contains my upload function
    vmb_client = vmb_controller()
    
    # Upload files asynchronously
    from multiprocessing import Process
    p = Process(target=vmb_client.upload_file, args=(<arguments>))
    p.start()
```

###### Here is a simplified version of my upload function:

```py
def upload_file(self, corp_index, filename):
    #
    # Set up new DB connection
    #
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    engine = create_engine(db_uri)
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    sess = Session()
    #
    # This does the API call to upload the file. It doesn't involve any DB interaction
    #
    results = self.call_upload_file(<arguments>)
    #
    # Track the uploaded file in the DB
    #
    command = f"""
        -- Insert new item in DB
        INSERT INTO corporate.vmb_items (corporation_key, onedrive_item_id, parent_id, type, name, created_datetime,
                        modified_datetime, path, web_url, child_count, size)
        VALUES ({corp_index}, '{res.get('id')}', '{res.get('parent_id')}', 'file', '{res.get('name').replace("'", "''")}',
            '{res.get('created_datetime')}', '{res.get('modified_datetime')}', '{res.get('path').replace("'", "''")}',
            '{res.get('web_url').replace("'", "''")}', {res.get('child_count')}, '{res.get('size')}');"""
    sess.execute(command)
    #
    # Update parent folder
    #
    command = f"""-- Update child count of parent folder
                UPDATE corporate.vmb_items AS i SET child_count = (SELECT COUNT(vmb_item_key) FROM corporate.vmb_items AS sub WHERE sub.parent_id = '{res.get('parent_id')}')
                    WHERE i.onedrive_item_id = '{res.get('parent_id')}';"""
    sess.execute(command)
    #
    # Cleanup
    #
    sess.commit()
    sess.close()
    engine.dispose()

    return results
```

Based on other posts I saw related to the errors I'm getting, I tried a couple different parameters in my `create_engine` call, but those didn't make any difference:

```py
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
corporate_engine = create_engine(db_uri, pool_pre_ping=True, poolclass=NullPool)
```

Comment: Has psycopg2 been compiled on the machine that is executing the code (that is, you are _not_ using psycopg2-binary)?

Comment: I think I'm using the compiled version. If I run `pip list | grep psycopg2`, the result is `psycopg2 2.8.3`. Hope that answers your question